# Error message in lme4::glmer: " 'what' must be a character string or a function"

Tags: r, lme4

I am running a multi-level model. I use the following commands with `validatedRS6` as the outcome, `random` as the predictor and `clustno` as the random effects variable.

```
new<-as.data.frame(read.delim("BABEX.dat", header=TRUE))
install.packages("lme4")
library(lme4)
model1<- glmer(validatedRS6 ~ random + (1|clustno), data=new, family=binomial("logit"), nAGQ = 1L)
```

However, I get the following error

> Error in do.call(new, c(list(Class = "glmResp", family = family), ll[setdiff(names(ll),  : 
>     'what' must be a character string or a function

I have absolutely no idea what has gone wrong and have searched the internet. I am sorry but I cannot provide the data as it is from an intervention which has yet to be published.

Comment: You need to at least post the results of `str(new)`. (Also but probably tangential, you should not need to wrap `as.data.frame` around the results of `read.delim`.)

Comment: I can reproduce this by simply **having a variable called 'new' in my global environment**.  Will fix.  Workaround: `new2 <- new; rm("new"); glmer(..., data=new2, ...)`

Answer (score 4):

(expanded from comment).

Congratulations, you found a bug in `lme4`! This is fixed now:

https://github.com/lme4/lme4/commit/9c12f002821f9567d5454e2ce3b78076dabffb54

It is caused by having a variable called `new` in the global environment (deep in the guts of the code, `lme4` uses `do.call(new,...)` and finds your variable `new` rather than the built-in function `new`).

You can install a patched version from Github using `devtools::install_github()` (but you'll need compilation tools etc.).  Alternately, there is a very simple workaround -- just call your variable anything other than `new` (you can't just copy it, i.e. `new2 <- new` -- you also have to make sure the old version is removed (`rm("new")`)).