# Error in sensitivity::fast99: “ 'what' must be a character string or a function”

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'd like to perform sensitivity analysis on a model with three uniformly distributed parameters:

```
install.packages("sensitivity")
library(sensitivity)
params <- c("param1","param2","param3")    
x <- fast99(model = myModel, factors = params, n = 1000, q = list("qunif","qunif","qunif"), q.arg = list(list(min=10, max=200), list(min=0.1, max=0.9), list(min=0.1, max=0.9)))
```

However, this gives me the following error:

`Error in do.call(q[j], c(list(p = g), q.arg[[j]])) : 
'what' must be a character string or a function`

This is the function `myModel`:

```
myModel <- function(X) {

#input parameters: convert from data frame to matrix.
X <- data.matrix(X)
#vector that holds the response values.
y <- vector()
#loop over the rows of X.
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
   #get the i-th row as parameter vector (string).  
   params <- paste(X[i,],collapse=" ")
   y[i] = shell(paste("C:\\Users\\name\\someApp.exe", params), intern = TRUE)
}
return(y)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: I've looked through this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801070/error-message-in-lme4glmer-what-must-be-a-character-string-or-a-function), but didn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: can you also post the `myModel` function?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Looks fairly dangerous to be altering "params" in a loop when you are also passing a vector of the same name to fast99(). Also the help page for `fast99` says there needs to be a `predict.`-method for any function being used.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat: You're right, that's dangerous. I changed the name of one of the ``params``variables, but the error is still there. In the documentation it says that you can either specifiy a function, **OR** a model with a ``predict``.

Comment: So it look as though the error is saying that the first argument to do.call is not a character value. Can you put in some debugging lines to print out the class of the first

Comment: Or report the output from: `str(  shell(paste("C:\\Users\\name\\someApp.exe", params[1]), intern = TRUE) )`

Comment: This is the output from ``str(shell(...)``:
Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr) : 
  character string expected as first argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the one who asked the question and I finally found the solution:
`fast99` requires the parameter `q` to be a vector of character strings. The error was caused because I specified `q`as a list.

So this causes the error:

```
x <- fast99( ..., q = list("qunif","qunif","qunif"), ...)
```

And this works:

```
x <- fast99( ..., q = c("qunif","qunif","qunif"), ...)
```

Comment: if this happens to you often enough, it might be worth contacting the maintainer of the package and submitting a "wishlist" item that users be protected from themselves by testing internally whether `q` is a `character` vector, and if not issuing a more informative error message ...